# choosing crystal when tracks are very close together

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, capacitance, crystal, tolerance

This is a circuit I am having trouble with. I made 20 units with the exact same setup.

Three units with this setup managed to work with 33pF ceramic caps with 20% tolerance and a crystal from Ebay.

The remaining units are failing yet nothing is smoking or showing discoloration. I even replaced the 20% ceramics with 5% npo caps and still nothing.

I think now the lucky units were working because the crystal load capacitance and ESR happened to be spot-on.

What I want to try to do since people here consider ebay as a flea market is buy crystals from digikey. But there are two types I could possibly choose from.

One with 18pF load capacitance and one with 20pF load capacitance. The ideal frequency I'm looking for is 22.1184Mhz.

When I look at my tracks between the crystal leads they're probably too close together and I should probably increase the parasitic capacitor value when calculating my crystal load capacitance value.

One source on the internet claims this math for crystal load:

```
 CL = C/2 + StrayC
```

Because the caps I will use are 5% 33pF, its actual value would be between 31.35pF and 34.65pF

Now diving those capacitor numbers by two, we get 15.675pF and 17.325pF respectively.

People say the normal stray capacitance value is between 2 and 5pF but isn't mine more due to tight track spacing? I don't understand. So if it was 2pF then values would be:

```
  17.675pF and 19.325pF
```

Which means an 18pF load capacitance crystal is my best bet, but my stray capacitance is probably higher since I'm using a socket for my micro controller.

If its 5pf stray, then values would be:

```
20.675pF and 22.325pF
```

Which means a 20pF load capacitance crystal is my best bet.

Somehow I think the 20pF load crystal is better for my situation but I could be wrong.

Am I best to choose a crystal with 20pF load capacitance or 18pF load capacitance? and yes I will still use a standard IC socket for the micro (AT89S52) that uses this crystal.

[image: circuit]

Comment: The "crystal from Ebay" is likely the problem.

Comment: If one were bound and determined to use eBay crystals one could make a test oscillator.  With care you could cook up an oscillator that'd indicate crystal activity, to boot.  Just set it up next to a trash can with your bag of crystals and start sorting good from bad.

Comment: Mike, you've produced twenty units of this, and rely on ebay-sourced crystals? Why? You've now got half about half a dozen electrical engineers that tell you that using crystals from ebay is a bad idea. Maybe, just maybe, spend USD 11.50 on [twenty oscillators](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ecs-inc/ECS-221-S-4X/X1109-ND/827600) that are of good quality instead of hunting bugs that have nothing to do with your design, but all with the fact that you make bad sourcing decisions.

Comment: (Edit: it's not half a dozen, but only five engineers telling you the problems are most likely related to your component quality in this and your previous question: @TimWescott, Matt Young, Sunnyskyguy EE75, Chris Stratton and myself.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'll bring it up to half a dozen..... Don't use eBay crystals if you want reliability!

Comment: This is why I come here, because when I initially ordered crystals a long time ago, I didn't realize there were multiple factors to consider but now that I know there are factors. I mean I could try oscillators if my PCB allowed them but I'm following the microcontroller's datasheet and sticking with crystals and caps.

Comment: how about sticking to **working** crystals and caps?

Comment: ah, sorry, I incorrectly labeled my link "oscillators". These are crystals.

Comment: Make that USD 5 for twenty crystals, [there are way cheaper crystals on digikey](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/9B-22.1184MBBK-B/887-1870-ND/3521963/?itemSeq=295000619)

Comment: Question is, who is the best manufacturer? You linked me to one crystal I already saw on that site. I don't want to buy a fluke.

Comment: 1. I would expect it to be cheaper to adjust your capacitor values to suit your crystal instead of adjusting your crystal to suit your capacitors. 2. If you think the stray capacitance value is higher, you should be adding less discrete capacitance in parallel, not more.

Comment: @Mike that crystal is sold on digikey. digikey simply doesn't sell any bad manufacturers. That's *literally* their job, and they take it seriously, because distributors are quicker out of business if large customers have systematic problems with them than you can say "free market".

Comment: Ok but since 5+ people here say Ebay is a terrible source for buying crystals, I could safely assume all my crystals from there are damaged including those unused. I mean its ok if the frequency is off a bit, just as long as the microcontroller starts. The datasheet suggests 30pF plus/minus 10pF but with my choice of npo 33pF, I'm always within range for the caps.

Answer (score 3):

*If you follow the recommended oscillator circuit*, a good quality active crystal should work with a load capacitance that's off a bit.  The problem isn't that it won't oscillate *at all*, the problem is that it'll oscillate at the wrong frequency.

Looking at your layout your oscillation frequency may be extra sensitive to temperature variations because FR-4 is a crappy dielectric, but it should **work**.

Comment: ok. The expected temperature of the circuit will be no more than 25 degrees celcius because it will be in a plastic enclosure and used in a game. And by wrong frequency, I'm guessing if I pick the lower load capacitance crystal and the math results in the need of a higher capacitance crystal, then the actual frequency is lower than the frequency printed on the crystal can? and yes I'm following the suggestions from the microcontroller datasheet itself. I'm going to guess that the remaining unused crystals I bought from ebay are trash now.

Answer (score 1):

Just some extended comments and errors in your design.

- ground plane adds more unwanted stray capacitance (to gnd) than coplanar tracks. Maybe <150 ppm  lower f,  if C is too high and <150 ppm high if C is too low.
- no thermal solder pads for SMD and XTAL parts. Each pad should be a thermal island of heat when soldering so you do not have to heat up long fat tracks.
- XTAL Solder time 3s max.. fat tracks. maybe you damaged the XTAL if too hot and too long.
- no datasheets, no idea if it is series or parallel resonant, no idea if it is fundamental or harmonic (overtone) type.
- no series current limiting R=4k7 typ. to limit unknown xx uW rating of XTAL
- **no test measurements.**

  - measure  Voltage on pins 18 (XTAL2=out) and 19 (XTAL1=in) with DVM or better with scope

    - if Vout = 5V, input is shorted to Gnd
    - if Vout ~ 2.5V may be oscillating but if no  clock , then ESR is too high or XTAL is damaged.

Comment: This is weird. one board is rather wacky. The voltage between VCC and ground is 5, but when I measured crystal directly, voltage is 5.4. If I measured the other way, I get 0.8V but the crystal pins aren't grounded. I measured that with my meter to make sure. I'm going to guess a broken crystal?

Comment: There is a CMOS inverter across those pins, how did you measure it? P18 is output

Comment: Try 1Meg across Xtal and verify output. The DMM leads will affect capacitance. The DMM has a hard time reading this RF but  you get weird  DC effects. A CMOS Logic Probe is better. Get one

Comment: Now I'm wondering if 6V is too much for the Ebay crystals to handle. My digikey crystals are currently in a postal truck. Because after 6V, the voltage measurement across the crystal is 0V which makes me think that the crystal is a short circuit at some frequencies, but when I measure manually for a short, there isn't one. I'm going to try digikey crystals and limit the voltage to 5.5 (via LM2940 regulator) like I do with the previous board that did work. Maybe that extra 0.5V was enough to destroy the crystal.

Comment: mike if your are measuring across the crystal, that is not what I asked, it should be with respect to 0V

Comment: In any event, I'm going to try digikeys crystals to see if it makes a dramatic difference

Comment: Did you exceed 3s solder time?

Comment: I recently got 24Mhz 20pF load capacitance crystals from a UK seller on Ebay. I ordered them long before I made this post. They did not want to work either. Makes me think maybe the crystal was operating at 26Mhz because my caps are 33pF and my micro won't support speed faster than 24Mhz. As for your question, for the first crystal I might have exceeded 3s, but for the last crystal, I used 2s at most for soldering.

Comment: If they were rated for 20pF then you two caps with the series equivalent of 20pF not 20 pF each. Eg 47pF on output p18 and 33pF on p19. Capiche?

Comment: It won’t resonate at 26MHz